# How to look at the command output?

Tags: plugin-cmake.vim

I'm trying to configure [cmake.vim](https://github.com/jalcine/cmake.vim) for my c++ projects, but it doesn't work for me even on initial stage. The following command:

```
:CMakeCreateBuild <build_dir>
```

just creates a build directory but it seems it doesn't invoke `cmake` to configure the project.

I see something in vim command line, it looks like a log of cmake.vim execution but it shows just a last line.

How to open full log of last command there and not a one line only?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to their [README page](https://github.com/jalcine/cmake.vim#getting-started) `:CMakeCreateBuild <build-dir-name>` only creates a new binary directory for your project so I think you are experiencing the expexted behavior.

Still according to the same page I think you need to run the following commands:

```
" Create a new binary directory for your clean project.
:CMakeCreateBuild <build-dir-name>

" Build all of the targets.
:CMakeBuild

" Clean up bad builds.
:CMakeClean
```

Comment: accordingly cmake workflow , first stage is a configuring , second one is a building . if you look at full version of the documentation you can see this : "*:CMakeCreateBuild*

`:CMakeCreateBuild` takes only one argument, the name of the directory that
the build directory will be. It'll fail if the name isn't one of the values
provided in `g:cmake_build_directories` so take care to use one of those.

It'll make the directory if it doesn't exist, remove `CMakeCache.txt` if it
exists (with confirmation) and invoke CMake within that directory.
"

Comment: look at last sentence

Answer (score 0):

You could run it again with the 'verbose' option set to 15 (you know, like `:set verbose=15`) to trace every ex command called by the plugin.